# How do I find binomial distribution using R?

Tags: r

Harry is a basketball player.His probability of making a free throw is 0.70. 
-> what is the probability that Harry makes his third free throw on his fifth shot?

things I have tried so far; given p=0.70   n = 5

```
sum(dbinom(3:5,n,p))
```

And I got 0.83, but I know that answer is 0.18.

```
pbinom(5,n,p)-pbinom(2,n,p)
```

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If he gets 3rd free throw on 5th shot, then

- the previous 4 shots have 2 free throws;
- the 5th shot is a free throw

Note, these two events are independent, while the probability of the first is `dbinom(2, 4, 0.7)`, and the probability of the last is 0.7. So

```
dbinom(2, 4, 0.7) * 0.7
# [1] 0.18522
```

---

Note, there is really a trap here. It is so easy to assume the answer as

```
dbinom(3, 5, 0.7)
# [1] 0.3087
```

But that only means we have 3 free throws out of 5 shots, which does not guarantees the 5th shot is a free throw.

Comment: "...which does not guarantees the 5th shot is a free throw." - I think that should be "which does not guarantees the 5th shot is a success" ? In fact, the whole thing should probably be framed in terms of successes or made shots, rather than 'free throws' as the outcomes. 'Free throws' are events, not outcomes.  But +1 :-)

Comment: Thanks guys. It was a great help.